# Archimedean property and Completeness

Tags: analysis

I know that Archimedean property equals Completeness axiom.

Is it possible to prove Archimedean property for real number without using Completeness axiom or equivalents of it?

Comment: The rational numbers are Archimedean, but not complete.

Comment: For real number

Comment: This raises the question of what you are allowed to say about the real numbers, since their characterizing property mustn't be mentioned in any form.